# programatically replace first occurence of string with sed or gnu sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace **only** the first occurence of `version: *` in a file.

So I have a working sed command that work with GNU sed ([source](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html)):

`sed -i '0,/\(.*"version"\): "\(.*\)",/s//\1: '"\"${NEW_VERSION}\",/" package-lock.json`

My problem is that i am executing this in scripts that also can run **without** GNU sed.

When i replace by `sed -i '1,/\(.*"version"\): "\(.*\)",/s//\1: '"\"${NEW_VERSION}\",/" package-lock.json` then it work without GNU sed but i have the following error when GNU sed is available:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

**EDIT: my main goal**

As requested, here is my initial goal:

In a `package.json` and/or a `package-lock.json` , i want to replace the first occurence of   `version: X.X.X` by     `version: Y.Y.Y` where `$NEW_VERSION` containers `Y.Y.Y`

Comment: Does it __have to__ be `sed`? `occurence of version: *` You seem to replace `"version": ".*"` not `version: *`. Why not use JSON aware tool to modify JSON?

Comment: Which non-gnu sed version supports `-i`?

Comment: It would be better if you provide your sample input and expected output

Comment: @KamilCuk no, but a tool by default in an alpine image would be the bast

Comment: @anubhava I added my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed:`

```sh
sed -i.bak -E '/(version: ).*/!{p;d;}
s//\1'"$NEW_VERSION"'/
:a
n
ba
' file
```

Alternatively this `awk` would also work:

```sh
awk -v ver="$NEW_VERSION" '!done && /^version:/{$2=ver; done=1} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check first occurrence by for example storing something in hold space.

```
sed '
   # If hold space is empty
   x;/^$/{x;
      # If there is a pattern, replace it and..
      /\("version": "\).*",/{
         s//\1'"$NEW_VERSION"'"/1
         # and hold the line.
         h;
      };x
   };x
'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to simplify the expressions, since I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to match with the double quotes and the comma, and I think they obscure the main point.  To replace just the first occurrence of `foo` with `repl`, you can do:

```
sed -e s/foo/repl/ -e ta -e p -e d -e :a -e n -e ba
```

The `t` command branches to the `:a` after a replacement is made, and the commands after `:a` just read and print each line without trying the substitution.

eg:

```
$ printf '%s\n' qux foo bar baz foo | sed -e s/foo/repl/ -e ta -e p -e d -e :a -e n -e ba
qux
repl
bar
baz
foo
```

But, this is really a lot easier with awk:

```
awk '/foo/ && !a{gsub("foo", "repl"); a = 1}1'
```